# How to protect the login credentials?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, https

I'm developing a web application based on a `React` (client side) and the `node js` (server side) which incorporates a user login. My question is there a sense to pass the user login credentials (login, password) using the `basic auth` protocol (the `auth` request header) if I'm using the `HTTPS` protocol to communicate? Am i right that using the `HTTPS` automatically makes the credential data encrypted by browser when the user sends a login form? Can there be any advantages in using the `basic auth` instead of just cookies to pass the credentials if using the `HTTPS`?

Comment: You mean `Basic` instead of `simple` right?

Comment: @Evert Yes, of course, just corrected it out:-)

Comment: @Evert So can You help me out with the question?